# Prevent Varnish to cache PHP code

Tags: wordpress, caching, varnish

I'm working on a Wordpress project which uses Varnish cache server. Although my project is on Wordpress but I'm pretty sure that this issue will be on any other CSM & framework too.

In one of the template, I have just used Wordpress core function to get the user id of the currently logged in user like:

```
echo is get_current_user_id();
```

The problem is because of the Varnish, it gives 0 but as soon as I disable Varnish it works perfectly.

So how to stop Varnish to stop caching PHP code?

Note: I'm totally new to the Varnish.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your complete Varnish VCL.

Answer (score 0):

Varnish is HTTP accelerator which caches HTML, css images, mainly used to accelerate the front end. It does not cache PHP.

But as per your problem, your output page is cached.

Varnish is getting a hit for the same page and showing the cached output. Try to pass the page in vcl and see if it is working or not.

normally frequent updating page like admin page or wordpress should be passed through varnish . Not hit .